# How to order decimal column by position in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to output values based on a column named DisplayOrder which contains values like:

```
1.1
1.2
2.3
2.1
2.2
5.2
5.3
5.1
```

I need to output these numbers based on it's position in another table which has values not in order like so:

```
2
5
1
```

and I want to output the values in the top table in order of position in the second table, but in order of decimal value like so:

```
2.1
2.2
2.3 
5.1
5.2
5.3
1.1
1.2
```

So far I've tried to insert into a temp table where the first part of the number is in this order:

```
INSERT INTO #Temp
SELECT DisplayOrder
FROM Questions
WHERE DisplayOrder LIKE @Search
```

The above code loops through Table 2 which assigns the individual value to @Search with + .% to get all of the values with the start of the decimal.

I read a few other posts where they mention that when data is inserted it's order is essentially lost and should be obtained when selecting for output.

Comment: Since tables have no inherent order, what do you mean by "another table which has values not in order" - do you have a column that *defines* the order to be applied? (Hint: you need one)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I have a table that is created by looping through a comma delimited string and inserting the separated values. That's a representation of the Second table. E.g. '2,5,1' gets turned into table two which dictates the order of table 1

Comment: Tables have no *inherent* order. Unless you're applying additional *numbering* of the values as you insert them, your table contains 3 rows. Whenever it's queried, it's not defined what *order* it returns those rows in, unless you apply an `ORDER BY` clause. You'll note that both answers so for supplied assume that such a numbering has taken place.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I have noticed and I'm currently incorporating the fields into my solution to see if it will work. Will update when I get it working

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @T1 table (nval money)
Insert into @T1 values
(1.1),
(1.2),
(2.3),
(2.1),
(2.2),
(5.2),
(5.3),
(5.1)

Declare @T2 table (RowNr int,nval money) -- Make RowNr and Identity(int)
Insert into @T2 values
(1,2),(2,5),(3,1)

Select A.*
 From @T1 A
 Join @T2 B on floor(a.nval)=B.nval
 Order By B.RowNr,A.nval
```

Returns

```
nval
2.10
2.20
2.30
5.10
5.20
5.30
1.10
1.20
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you are not showing your tables. Let's say they look like this:

**table data**

```
value
1.1
1.2
2.3
2.1
...
```

**table datasort**

```
intvalue   displayorder
2          1
5          2
1          3
...
```

Join the tables and order by displayorder first and value afterwards:

```
select
from data
join datasort on datasort.intvalue = trunc(data.value)
order by datasort.displayorder, data.value;
```